# How to get current user profile from instagram app from my own app?

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

I need know if the user authenticated from my app by the instagram api is the same that the current user in the instagram app.
For example, my app conects with the api for an user A, and the api send me the access token of user A. But intagram app into my device have an user login with user B. How to know if the user A in my app (conected with the api) is the same that user B (login in instagram app).

Comment: I think instagram api are available on their site. Refer that http://instagram.com/developer/#

Comment: thanks, I edit the question, can you answer other time my edited question?

Answer (score 0):

This information is not shared between apps.  When you try to auth a user into your app, they use OAuth to provide you a token.  Even though they may seem connected because a user can choose the current logged in user or and Instagram will save time by using their current auth session to generate a token for you, it is tied to your client id/app and other details are a black box to you app.

You can not query the instagram app for its token/user as it would be a huge security risk where apps could collect all social identities for a user.